# Bogolubov coefficients calculation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime, pair-production

I'm studing the Hawking effect in a two dimensional Schwarzchild spacetime.
I have the modes:

$
\phi(t,r^*) = \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{d k}{(2 \pi)^{1/2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \Omega}}\left[ e^{-i(\Omega t - k r^*)} \hat{b}_k^- + e^{i(\Omega t - k r^*)} \hat{b}_k^+  \right] \\
    \phi(T,X) = \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{d k}{(2 \pi)^{1/2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega}}\left[ e^{-i(\omega T - k X)} \hat{a}_k^- + e^{i(\omega T - k X)} \hat{a}_k^+  \right],
$

The two modes (Eddington(tortoise) and Kruskal) can be connected by a Bogolubov tranformation:

$
v_j = \sum_i (A_{ij}u_i + B_{ij}u^*_i).
$

The coefficient I want to find is $B_{ij}$, which should be

$
B_{ij} = -(v_i, u_j^*) = -i \int_\Sigma ( v_i \partial_\mu u^*_j - u^*_j \partial_\mu v_i) \sqrt{-g} d \Sigma^\mu.
$

Can anyone can help me to perform this integral, I have no idea.

P.S.) The final result should be something like this:

$
 \beta_{\omega \Omega} = \sqrt{\frac{\Omega}{\omega}} \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{d u}{2 \pi}  e^{i \Omega u - i\omega U}.
$